# how to place ads below or above BottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation, google-mobile-ads

I want to place `google_mobile_ads` Banner Ad just above or below the `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter.

I tried to place the BottomNavigationBar in `Container` ad add Margin, but there is no option to add 2 children inside the Container.

I tried to add a `Column` widget inside the `BottomNavigationBar` but the column goes to the up top of the page.

Any ideas on how I can make a place for `google_mobile_ads` just above or below the `BottomNavigationBar`?

I can share the code, but I need advice or guidance or pointers on how it can be achieved.

Comment: It's better if you provide a minimum example for us. In the meantime, a Container can only have one child, whereas a column can have many. You should constrain your column so that it does not fill all the page. Something like a container would work.

Comment: Can you suggest how I can constraint the column so that it can stick to the bottom part of the page and not take up the whole page.  The body is inside the singlechildscrollview which has a listview builder inside. I will paste the once I am back at my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.
one would be to separate your scaffold and Ad container like this:

```
return Column(
    children:[
        Expanded(child: Scaffold(),
        SizedBox(height: 50, child: AdContainer())
    ]
)
```

another way would be to add it in the bottom nav bar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
                         height = 200,
                         child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                        BottomNav(),
                                        AdContainer()
                                    ]
                         )
                     )
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you. The second option didnt work for some reason so took the first route.

Answer (score 9):

That's how I dealt with it;

```
bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          AdvertisementWidget(),
          BottomNavigationBar(),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: This looks good too.

Comment: `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in a column in MaterialApp and expand Scaffold body to fill Ad to the bottom

```
MaterialApp:
       Column(:[
            Expanded(Scaffold),
            AdWidget,
        ])
```